# Edge attributes of multiple shortest paths (in dictionary) using networkx

Tags: networkx

I have an additional question to the problem, which is solved here: [Edge attributes of shortest path using networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683321/edge-attributes-of-shortest-path-using-networkx)

I want to have the attributes of all shortest paths in a transport network. So in the case described above,  @swatchai answered how to get attributes of one path. But in my network, I have from Amsterdam to the rest of the world 300 shortest paths. The script looks like this:

```py
sp2 = nx.shortest_path(g, source='NLAMS', weight='weight')
for key, value in sp2.items():
    print(key, ' : ', value)
```

It works till here!
In the answer of @swatchai he suggested the following script as answer, but I think it doesn't work for me because it is a dictionary instead of a list.

```py
pathGraph2 = nx.path_graph(sp2)  # does not pass edges attributes

for edgeatr in pathGraph2.edges(): #print from_node, to_node, edge's attributes
    print(edgeatr, g.edges[edgeatr[0], edgeatr[1]])
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need to use the back tics to create a code block correctly lol

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you may be confused between what you obtain when you do:

```
>>> nx.shortest_path(g, source=1, target=2, weight='weight')
[1, 7, 2]
```

versus

```
>>> nx.shortest_path(g, source=1, weight='weight')
{1: [1], 0: [1, 0], 5: [1, 5], 7: [1, 7], 4: [1, 0, 4], 2: [1, 0, 2], 6: [1, 5, 6], 3: [1, 0, 4, 3]}
```

As you can see the second one gives you all **targets** from source plus all **paths**.

To create the `path_graph` you can only use the `path`.

Here is an example:

```
# Create a random graph with 8 nodes, with degree=3
g = nx.random_regular_graph(3, 8, seed=None)

# Add 'cost' attributes to the edges
for (start, end) in g.edges:
    g.edges[start, end]['cost'] = np.random.randint(1,10)

SOURCE = 1
sp_SOURCE = nx.shortest_path(g, source=SOURCE, weight='weight')

for target, path in sp_SOURCE.items(): 
    print("Shortest path from SOURCE to {} is {}".format(target,path))
    pathGraph = nx.path_graph(path)   # for each target we create a path_graph
    for ea in pathGraph.edges():
        #print from_node, to_node, edge's attributes
        print("\t", ea, g.edges[ea[0], ea[1]])
```